# Fedora black screen

Tags: fedora

The Fedora CD runs well, but after installing Fedora and trying to run it from my HD, I got a black screen.

I hit CTRL+ALT+F1, there were messages. I tried typing there and hitting enter, nothing happened.

I hit CTRL+ALT+F3, there was a message. I tried typing there and nothing appeared.

There are posts in forums about Fedora`s black screen.

I tried installing system-config-display, but I got an error message saying I need python abi and libpython both higher than version 2.6.

I tried installing the nv instead of the nouveau driver, but I have to run system-config-display --reconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using NVIDIA card and it's caused by the driver, you may try nvidia driver provided by rpmfusion: http://fclose.com/b/1484/ and [nVidia official Howto](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) from RPM Fusion

Or you may try adding `nomodeset` to the kernel boot parameter.